# PregMatchAll always returns 0 even while regex matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have been doing this:

```
preg_match_all('!<div class="ratings">\s*?(.*?)\s*<\/div>!', $result, $match);
```

for my this block

```
<div class="ratings">
<h4><a href="https://www.abcd.com/star-ratings">Sex 
<i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i><i class="icon-star-filled 
highlight"></i><i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i><i 
class="icon-star-filled"></i><i class="icon-star-filled"></i></a></h4>
<h4><a href="https://www.abcd.com/star-ratings">Sex 
<i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i><i class="icon-star-filled 
highlight"></i><i class="icon-star-filled highlight"></i><i 
class="icon-star-filled"></i><i class="icon-star-filled"></i></a></h4>
</div>
```

But my match always returns zero while doing

```
print_r($match[1]);
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex = EVIL!  Please use an XML/HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flag `s` to your pattern
`!<div class="ratings">\s*?(.*?)\s*<\/div>!s`
http://xregexp.com/flags/

Comment: Thanks that worked. How to read h4 tags inside div? Let's say I have 3 h4 tags inside div.

Comment: ```!<h4>(.*?)<\/h4>!s```

Comment: I have edited the div block. let say I have multiple h4 tags. If I am doing count it will give 0. :(. I want the count to be equal to the number of h4 tags. How to achieve that?

Comment: RegExp above works fine. ```count($matches[1])``` should be equal to h4 tags count.
You can check it here https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html

Comment: Its giving me 1